# Spring Boot Application hung while deploying on JBoss 6.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, jboss

i have a very concerning issue related with Spring Boot 1.5.16 and JBoss 6.4 EAP.

**Introduction**
The application is archived as War and it is contained into a EAR with another Spring Application and an Angular as well.

**Problem**
As far I test the deploy in local, none issue appears. Althought in local environment the War is loaded correctly into Jboss, in a remote test server the run would hang during the Spring Boot Application running in this specific phase.

```
10:04:53,056 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
10:04:53,056 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
10:04:53,058 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
10:04:53,059 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
10:04:53,155 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
10:04:53,157 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
10:04:53,247 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) JBAS018210: Register web context: /ng-app
10:04:53,252 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) JBAS018210: Register web context: /spring-boot-app
10:04:53,252 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) JBAS018210: Register web context: /spring-app
10:04:53,294 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/spring-app]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
10:04:53,306 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/spring-boot-app]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
10:04:53,522 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/spring-app]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
10:04:53,525 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
```

Despite the app is being loaded and run correctly (the whole app works), if the application is restarted, Spring Boot Application won't close its session successfully. The result is that on the new loading phase, the JVM will have doubled its resources occupied and so on.

**What I did**
I focused essentially to this message:

```
2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
```

It might be an issue related to multiple context initialization? I provide you my relevant classes and I hope for your advice.

**ServletInitializer**.class

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(ApplicationConfig.class);
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(application).web(false).run(args);    }
}
```

**ApplicationConfig**.class

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
@Order
public class ApplicationConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

//    @PostConstruct
//    void init() {
//        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
//    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        application.web(false);
        return application.sources(ServletInitializer.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        return new DispatcherServlet();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {

        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
                dispatcherServlet(), "/*");

        registration
                .setName(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return registration;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        System.setProperty(AbstractEnvironment.ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME, "test");
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }
}
```

**Some Details**
I have a JNDI Database Connection that works correctly at least in local environment.
I have no web.xml.
This is the springboot app sub-deployment in **jboss-deployment-structure**.xml

```xml
<sub-deployment name="CRVbusinessService.war">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.xml.rpc.api"/>
            <module name="javax.wsdl4j.api"/>
        </dependencies>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.xalan"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl"/>
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="restService.war">
        <local-last value="true" />
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.jpa2.1"/>
        </dependencies>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j"/>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
            <module name="javax.persistence.api" />
            <module name="org.hibernate" />
            <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
            <module name="javaee.api" />
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>
    <module name="deployment.jpa2.1" >
        <module-alias name="jpa2.1"/>
        <resources>
            <resource-root path="hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar" />
        </resources>
    </module>
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Why are you using <code>snippet</code> blocks for console output, Java source, POM?

Comment: at least it is a bit formatted

Comment: No, `<!-- language: lang-...` is responsible for that, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) for more details.